# How to link .lib library in linux

Tags: gcc

I'm pretty new to c programming and want to port a windows c application to linux. My code uses a .lib file `va_g729.lib` - is it possible to use the same library in Linux and compile it with gcc?

All my `.c` and `.h` files along with the one `.lib` files are in the same directory. What I'm doing now is executing this command in the directory:

```
gcc *.c -lm
```

and I get following errors:

```
lbcodec2.c:(.text+0xa6b): undefined reference to `va_g729a_init_encoder'
lbcodec2.c:(.text+0xa83): undefined reference to `va_g729a_encoder'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is it possible to link the `.lib` file and compile with gcc?

Thanks.

Comment: `lib` files seem to be Windows specific. On Linux static library is `.a` and shared library is `.so`. Or I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like we can not compile the `.lib` file. I had to compile a `.a` file for linux from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc *.c -lm -lYourFile.lib -o yourExecutable
```

you might have to explicitly link your .lib file.

Comment: The `.lib` file is in my working direcoty, gcc does not find it. I tried explicityly mentioning the path with:
    gcc *.c -lm -lva_g729.lib -L/home/shantanu/workspace/ConverterTest/src

Still gcc can not find and says: 
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lva_g729.lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status