# Can or how Android studio use c++ static library *.lib (compiled for windows)?

Tags: android, static, cross-compiling

Our project needs a third party library from another company and it is not open source. They provided *.h and *.lib compiled for windows (linux as well), but no cpp.

I didn't think android could use it but I still have tried it in NDK because I have never touch android studio before.

There are many questions, but it all comes to the question, **is it possible to use *.lib in android studio(or VS cross-compile) without the cpp of that library**?

If the answer is no, I think the only option for us is to request the android version of the library (*.so and *.a files). **Is this correct?**

Comment: The third party library will need to be built for the proper CPU and OS. If you have a version for Windows and Linux, you don't have one for Android. Is the Android target a desktop system? If not, it's unlikely you have a version compiled for the proper CPU, either. Contact the vendor.

Comment: a) .lib is windows specific format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803754/how-to-link-lib-library-in-linux b) You still only have x86 binaries (I assume) so it can't run on Android devices with ARM processors, which is the majority.